# Is it possible to update a notification silently in Android O?

Tags: android-8.0-oreo

Previously I used setSound(null) but with the new notification channels this doesn't work.

So I could create yet another channel (already have around 10) that says Notification Updates and set that one to a null value for sound? Is that the only way to work around this? And if the user is stupid enough (there are always some) to set a sound for this category he will get multiple sounds when we update the existing alert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried using [`NotificationCompat.Builder.setOnlyAlertOnce()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setOnlyAlertOnce(boolean))?

> Set this flag if you would only like the sound, vibrate and ticker to
>   be played if the notification is not already showing.

It seems to do exactly what you want. :)